# Python - new list by applying some rules on the consecutive elements

Tags: python, arrays

This problem has given me some headaches and I'm trying to solve it without massively over-complicating things. I'm not looking for a code, only if someone can steer me into the best way I could solve this.
I have a list of arrays like this `[[1,'A'][3,'B'],[8,'C'],[10,'A']...]` and so on.

The index 0 of each array is some unit that always goes towards a higher number, though not always by the same increase. The index 1 of the array can be 'A', 'B' or 'C', 'D'.  What I need to get is a new list where I will join some arrays into a new list by applying some rules as:

1. if there are **minimum** three consecutive 'B' or 'C' in the list of arrays, in the new list that should come as 'X', and I should take index 0 of the first one in the list. So

E.g: 
if the list is:

```
L1 = [[1,'A'],[4,'B'],[6,'C'],[10,'B],[12,'B],[15,'A']
```

I should get L2 as:

```
[[1,'A'],[4,'X'],[15,'A']
```

2. If there are **minimum** three pairs of B, A then I should mark join them and mark that as Y:

   `L1 = [[1,'A'],[4,'B'],[6,'A'],[10,'B'],[12,'A],[15,'B'],[20,'A'],[25,'A']]`

L2 should be:

```
[[1,'A'],[4,'Y'],[25,'A']]
```

3. If there are **minimum** three triples of consecutive B,A,A i should join them and mark them as 'Z'

So, if:

```
L1 = [[1,'A'],[4,'B'],[6,'A'],[10,'A'],[12,'B],[15,'A'],[16,'A'],[18,'B],[20,'A'],[22,'A'],[25,'A']
```

L2 should be:

```
[[1,'A'],[4,'Z'],[25,'A']]
```

So my (very mechanical) intuition goes like this:

- Start with Rule3: Iterate over L1 by step 3, taking 9 arrays of the list at a time, comparing each of them to see if they match **B**, A, A, **B**, A, A, **B,** A, A pattern, and fill in a new list, let's say L1a. That could give me a some duplicates of Z, which I should iterate once again to "clean" it up, into a new L1b list.
- Apply Rule2 to L1b, same principle, just go by step 2, comparing 6 arrays of the list if they match **B**, A, **B**, A, **B**, A. That also gives duplicates which I should clean up, let's say i've come to a new list L1d.
- Apply Rule1 to the last list L1d, go by step of 1, comparing 3 arrays at time if any of them are B or C at index 1. That also again could gives me a lot of duplicates in the new list I should clean up again.

Now, this would most probably work, but it seems to me like ugly, over-complicated code. I sense there must be a simpler approach I just can't see it at the moment.

Comment: Well, if your logic is complex to begin with, your code is going to be complex as well. The steps you've enumerated seem appropriate for what you want to achieve. If you want anyone to think of a better way to approach this, you need to tell us *why* you want to achieve it (what's your end goal with the code), so we can (maybe) come up with a solution outside of the given rules.

Comment: @jfaccioni at the level of abstraction I'm aware of A B and C are types of discrete signals which when combined make other type of signal together (X, Y, Z), and the integers are time units for when they begin. My current approach as it seems to me would result in overly expressive and redundant code. I was hoping someone might point to me some corners I could cut. On the other hand, this approach might be better for understandable code.

Comment: You would probably benefit from modelling your signals as a proper Signal class in Python, then you could define what happens when you add Signals A, B and C together. A TimeSeries class that holds a bunch of Signals inside could be another abstraction layer. The reason why these abstactions help to make your code less complex is that it allows you to treat the signals as proper "things" in Python, instead of numbers and letters inside lists of lists. But it requires learning about classes and OOP in Python, if you don't know that already.

Comment: Also there may be a Python package out there that deals with discrete signals across time, so that you don't need to start from scratch (it's not my area of study so I can't tell if if there actually is one).